# How to force runtime error for missing arguments in Castle Windsor TypedFactory

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, abstract-factory

I am using CastleWindsor with their TypedFacility feature.

I have a group of about 50 classes that derive from an abstract base class.  They each have there own interface.  At load time I Register the concrete class to the interface.

There are a few interfaces in the TypedFacility:

1. `T CreateService<T>(string username)`
2. `T Create<T>`

The base class requires one argument in the constructor (username).

I would like to show a runtime error if someone tries to create a class that requires a username, with the Create instead of CreateService.  Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: Are you sure you want "compile error" when "someone tries to create a class"? You can try creating 2 TypedFactories behind two interfaces and avoid that. Otherwise you can do it inside FactoryMethod.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like that :

```
  Component.For<ITypedFactoryComponentSelector>().ImplementedBy<MyServicesTypedFactorySelector>(),
```

In the selector you have the type and the arguments :

```
public class MyServicesTypedFactorySelector : ITypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
    public Func<IKernelInternal, IReleasePolicy, object> SelectComponent(MethodInfo method, Type type, object[] arguments)
    {
        string username = arguments.Length > 0 ? (string)arguments[0] : null;
        var parameterlessConstructor = theType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        //if there is no parameterless ctor and string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) 
        // throw InvalidOperationException($"no username provided for {type.GetName().Name}");

        ....
    }   
}
```